# Tkinter, Entry widget, is detecting input text possible?

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, tkinter

I have an Entry widget on a simple calculator. The user can choose to enter an equation via the keypad. I was wondering if there was a way to detect a character(from the keypad in my case) being typed into the Entry widget. So, focus is on the widget, user presses '4', it comes up on the widget... can I detect this act, for basic purposes of logging the input?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every time you press a key inside a Tkinter window, a `Tkinter.Event` instance is created.  All you need to do is access that instance.  Here is a simple script that demonstrates just how:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Entry

root = Tk()

def click(key):
    # print the key that was pressed
    print key.char

entry = Entry()
entry.grid()
# Bind entry to any keypress
entry.bind("<Key>", click)

root.mainloop()
```

`key` (being a `Tkinter.Event` instance) contains many different attributes that can be used to get almost any type of data you want on the key that was pressed.  I chose to use the `.char` attribute here, which will have the script print what each keypress is.

Comment: I decided to accept this answer as I found it straight-forward and easy to understand at my level of experience and it lead directly to me working up a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. There are a few different ways to do this, in fact.

You can create a [`StringVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), attach it to the `Entry`, and `trace` it for changes; you can [`bind`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) all of the relevant events; or you can add a [validation command](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) that fires at any of several different points in the sequence. They all do slightly different things.

When a user types `4`, there's a key event with just the `4` in it (which doesn't let you distinguish whether the user was adding `4` to the end, or in the middle, or replacing a whole selected word, or…), and then a modification event is fired with the old text,* and then the "key" or "all" validation function is called with the (proposed) new text, and the variable is updated with the (accepted) new text (unless the validation function returned false, in which case the `invalidcommand` is called instead).

---

I don't know which one of those you want, so let's show all of them, and you can play around with them and pick the one you want.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def validate(newtext):
    print('validate: {}'.format(newtext))
    return True
vcmd = root.register(validate)

def key(event):
    print('key: {}'.format(event.char))

def var(*args):
    print('var: {} (args {})'.format(svar.get(), args))
svar = tk.StringVar()
svar.trace('w', var)

entry = tk.Entry(root,
                 textvariable=svar, 
                 validate="key", validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))
entry.bind('<Key>', key)
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

The syntax for variable trace callbacks is a bit complicated, and not that well documented in Tkinter; if you want to know what the first two arguments mean, you need to read the Tcl/Tk docs, and understand how Tkinter maps your particular `StringVar` to the Tcl name `'PY_VAR0'`… Really, it's a lot easier to just build a separate function for each variable and mode you want to trace, and ignore the args.

The syntax for validation functions is even more complicated, and a lot more flexible than I've shown. For example, you can get the inserted text (which can be more than one character, in case of a paste operation), its position, and all kinds of other things… but none of this is described anywhere in the Tkinter docs, so you will need to go [the Tcl/Tk docs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7). The most common thing you want is the proposed new text as the argument, and for that, use `(vcmd, '%P')`.

---

Anyway, you should definitely play with doing a variety of different things and see what each mechanism gives you. Move the cursor around or select part of the string before typing, paste with the keyboard and with the mouse, drag and drop the selection, hit a variety of special keys, etc.

---

* I'm going to ignore this step, because it's different in different versions of Tk, and not very useful anyway. In cases where you really need a modified event, it's probably better to use a `Text` widget and bind `<<Modified>>`.

Comment: Thanks for in-depth answer. It's going to take me a little while to absorb all of this, as I haven't come across this whole validation business with the Entry widget before, and there's a lot of new information for me here.

Comment: @Totem: Yeah, it's unfortunate that validation commands are what you want 80% of the time, but aren't mentioned anywhere in the tutorial, and aren't described at all in the Tkinter reference docs. So people try to build the same thing by catching `<Key>` and trying to figure out what the new string will be (or, less often, by tracing the var and then trying to revert an invalid change after the fact).

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to do simple things without using trace module you can try

```
    def objchangetext(self, textwidget):
        print(textwidget.get())  #print text out to terminal

    text1 = tk.Entry(tk.Tk()) 
    text1.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda event, arg=(0): objchangetext(text1))
```