# How to enable a button when some text is entered in tkinter entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently i have a scenario where buttons are disabled.Now i want to enable the buttons when some input is entered by the user in tkinter entry widget.

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: You should post a [mcve] of your code. Do you want the buttons to be enabled when the user hits the `Enter` key, or as soon as they start typing into the Entry widget?

Comment: I would have done that but it is my official code,so can't share.I want the buttons to enable as soon as user starts typing.Thanks!

Comment: We don't want to see your full program, just a short example that illustrate your problem, as described in the link I posted above. But anyway, furas has answered your question. FWIW, if you'd posted an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would have made it easy for answerers to modify that code to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can `bind()` function to `Entry` which will be executed when user press `<Key>`.

See `bind()` and `<Key>` in [Events and Binding](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148242/tkinter-entry-widget-is-detecting-input-text-possible) and as @Furas said you can bind function to Entry, something like this

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Entry   
root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root) #"frame" represents the parent window, where the entry widget should be placed.

frame.pack()
#GUI widgets
entry = Entry(frame, width=80) #The syntax of an entry widget 

entry.pack(side='right')

#callbacks
def enableEntry():
    entry.configure(state="normal")
    entry.update()

def disableEntry():
    entry.configure(state="disabled")
    entry.update()



def click(key):
    #print the key that was pressed
     print key.char    


var = StringVar()
disableEnButton = Radiobutton(frame, text="Disable", variable=var, value="0", command=disableEntry)
disableEnButton.pack(anchor=W)
enableEnButton = Radiobutton(frame, text="Enable", variable=var, value="1", command=enableEntry)
enableEnButton.pack(anchor=W)


#Bind entry to any keypress
entry.bind("<Key>", click)   
root.mainloop() #This is necessary for the event loop to service events such as button clicks
```