# How to check for a character in an input while it's being written?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm creating a password manager, and my code is somewhat close to this,
I was wondering if there's a way to check for a character inside a string while it's still being written (i.e. before the user clicks Enter), so that I can change the color of the line that says "An uppercase character" to green when the user inputs an uppercase character, and goes back to original character if the user deletes the character.

```
from termcolor import colored
from getpass import getpass

import string

def check_for_owasp_standards(password):
    uppercase_letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    lowercase_letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    digits = string.digits
    special_characters = "!@#$%^&*()-_"

    length_is_over_8 = False            
    contains_uppercase_letter = False
    contains_lowercase_letter = False
    contains_digit = False
    contains_special_character = False
    Checklist = []

    if len(password) >= 8 :     
        length_is_over_8 = True
    Checklist.append(length_is_over_8)

    for character in password:
        if character in uppercase_letters:
            contains_uppercase_letter = True
            break
    Checklist.append(contains_uppercase_letter)

    for character in password:
        if character in lowercase_letters:
            contains_lowercase_letter = True
            break
    Checklist.append(contains_lowercase_letter)

    for character in password:
        if character in digits:
            contains_digit = True
            break
    Checklist.append(contains_digit)

    for character in password:
        if character in special_characters:
            contains_special_character = True
            break
    Checklist.append(contains_special_character)

    if False in Checklist:
        return False
    else:
        return True

print(colored("According to OWASP password standards 2021 your master password must contain the following :", "magenta"))
print(colored("*An uppercase character", "magenta"))
print(colored("*A lowercase character", "magenta"))
print(colored("*A digit", "magenta"))
print(colored("*Length has to be 8 or more characters\n", "magenta"))

master_password = getpass(colored("Enter your master password : ", "blue"))
if not check_for_owasp_standards(master_password):
    print(colored("Password does not meet the standards, let's try again.\n", "yellow"))
else:
    print(colored("Master password saved successfully!", "green"))
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this isn't possible just from the command line, because there you just type data in an input stream and once you press Enter it's passed to your program, at which point it's too late. But with a [GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148242/tkinter-entry-widget-is-detecting-input-text-possible) you can have an event that is called on each key press, where you can check the validity of the password, make error messages appear/disappear, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a solution to your problem.

**This is a video showing how it works on my console >> [YouTube](https://youtu.be/rxk1G5kWjtE).**

**You can get the whole code, organised here >> [Github](https://github.com/KamilMatejuk/University/blob/master/Python/Password_Validator_Cmd.py).**

### And here is explanation:

You will need to turn off console output, then capture each keypress, and at the end turn console output back on.

For this you will need `from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener`, which works basically like this:

```py
def on_release(key):
    print(key)
    if key in [Key.enter, Key.esc]:
        return False

with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

which will basically print every pressed key, and stop working when pressing Enter or Esc.
Tp stop it from being visible you will disable it by `os.system("stty -echo")` and enable back with `os.system("stty echo")`

### Here is how I changed your code:

This method is similar to your `check_for_owasp_standards(password)` but will return a list of booleans for each standard that need to be checked:

```py
def checkStandards(password):
    uppercase_letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    lowercase_letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    digits = string.digits
    special_characters = "!@#$%^&*()-_"

    length_is_over_8 = False            
    contains_uppercase_letter = False
    contains_lowercase_letter = False
    contains_digit = False
    contains_special_character = False
    checklist = []

    if len(password) >= 8 :     
        length_is_over_8 = True
    checklist.append(length_is_over_8)

    for character in password:
        if character in uppercase_letters:
            contains_uppercase_letter = True
            break
    checklist.append(contains_uppercase_letter)

    for character in password:
        if character in lowercase_letters:
            contains_lowercase_letter = True
            break
    checklist.append(contains_lowercase_letter)

    for character in password:
        if character in digits:
            contains_digit = True
            break
    checklist.append(contains_digit)

    for character in password:
        if character in special_characters:
            contains_special_character = True
            break
    checklist.append(contains_special_character)
    return checklist
```

Next function will show this information as coloured. Green for accepted, red for not. The easiest way to show changes, overring previous lines written to console is to clear all console.

```py
def updateStandards(password):
    # clear console
    os.system('clear')
    # check
    standards = checkStandards(password)
    print(accept("Length >= 8", standards[0]))
    print(accept("Contains uppercase letter", standards[1]))
    print(accept("Contains lowercase letter", standards[2]))
    print(accept("Contains digit", standards[3]))
    print(accept("Contains special character", standards[4]))
```

using

```py
def accept(text, accepted=False):
    if accepted:
        return f'\033[32;1m{text}\033[0m' # green
    else:
        return f'\033[31;1m{text}\033[0m' # red
```

The main function will look like this. It will first reset global variable storing user input to empty string. Then show all rules for password. Then ask user for password and turn off showing in console. At the end, it will turn it back.

```py
def getPassword():
    try:
        # reset stored input to empty string
        global user_input
        user_input = ''
        # show rules for password
        updateStandards('')
        # ask for password
        print('Write your password:')
        # turn off showing input
        os.system("stty -echo")
        # collect keys until ENTER/ESC
        with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()
            input()
    except:
        print(traceback.print_exc())
    finally:
        # turn on showing input
        os.system("stty echo")
```

The last part is to write listener for key press:

```py
def on_release(key):
    global user_input
    # store key
    k = str(key).replace('\'', '')
    if len(k) == 1:
        user_input += k
    # delete last char
    if key == Key.backspace:
        user_input = user_input[:-1]

    updateStandards(user_input)
    print('Write your password:', ''.join('*' for _ in range(len(user_input))))

    # Stop listener
    if key in [Key.enter, Key.esc]:
        finished(user_input)
        return False
```

When user end writing password, you can do anything you want with it:

```py
def finished(password):
    # do what you need to do, e.g. store password somewhere
    standards = checkStandards(password)
    if all(standards):
        print('Your password is:', password)
    else:
        print('Your password should meet all the rules')
```